# Hide slider control nav when moving down at home page

Tags: slider, hide, controls, html

I wish on this HOME page http://soulskydesign.com/RALE%20Engineering/Predlog_dizajna/index-2.php to hide slide controls (1,2,3,4...) when I moving down. How can I do it?
When I moving down now I can see slider controls behind main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I miss read your question before. This is easily achievable using

```
z-index
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

What you want to do is put your navigation bar that has your menu to a higher z-index so nothing will be shown in front because other elements have a lower z-index. z-index:99999 would fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you L1ghtk3ira but I could not implemented your solution.
I still need help.

Comment: I misread your question the first time, I changed my answer, this is how you fix your problem, very easy.